# Где в post-запросе передаются параметры?

Tags: php, http, post

В стандарте HTTP есть 3 составляющие: стартовая строка, заголовки и тело.

Когда отправляю GET-запрос, то все параметры идут вместе с URI. Например

```
GET /index.php?name='myname'&age=26 HTTP/1.1
```

А когда я передаю те же самые данные, но методом POST, то эти параметры name и age где передаются? В теле запроса? В заголовках? Как выглядит этот HTTP-запрос?

Имеется ввиду чистый HTTP-запрос, как прописано в протоколе.

Если переформулировать вопрос. PHP, когда формирует массив `$_POST`, то данные этого массива из какой части HTTP-запроса берет?
В случае с `$_GET` все понятно, берет из URI. А с `$_POST` неясно.

Comment: В теле HTTP запроса

Comment: можно в Chrome на живых примерах посмотреть F12->Network->запрос->Headers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Итак, подытожу всё что тут сказали

**GET**
Передаётся в URL

```
GET https://example.com/comments?page=2&pageSize=10
```

**POST** 
Передаёт данные в теле

```
POST https://example.com/comments HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json

{
    "name": "sample",
    "time": "Wed, 21 Oct 2015 18:27:50 GMT"
}
```

Заголовок **content-type** определяет как данные будут переданы (JSON или кодированы url-encoded) таким образом сервер поймёт как их обработать.

На заметку:

**GET**

- Могут кэшироваться
- Остаются в истории браузера
- Могут быть/стать "закладкой"
- Не должны использоваться для передачи паролей и всего такого
- Имеют ограничение по длине (URL и в некоторых браузерах свои
  заморочки)

**POST**

- Никогда не кэшируются
- Не остаются в истории браузера
- Не могут быть/стать "закладкой"
- Не имеют таких ограничений по длине (обычно в браузерах и на web серверах есть ограничение по умолчанию)

Comment: например, отправили POST, нас перебросило на другую страницу, жмем назад и браузер спрашивает - повторить отправку данных из формы? как вы это объясните?

Comment: @Lex, такое происходит, если предыдущая веб-страница была получена метдом POST (странный сайт, почему они просто не перенаправляют в этом случае), и браузер выдаёт запрос на повторную отправку такого же запроса, который потенциально может привести в серьёзному изменению данных.

Comment: @LexHobbit как и написал mymedia это неправильно спроектированное приложение что делать чтобы так не происходило можно прочитать здесь https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

Данные POST запроса передаются в теле. То есть стартовая строка, потом заголовки, пустая строчка, а дальше идут параметры POST. Часто в формате url-encoded (formdata) - это как в адресной сроке у GET запроса, но в последнее время есть тенденция передавать в теле json. Формат кодировки запроса определяется по заголовку Content-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

> А когда я передаю те же самые данные, но методом POST, то как выглядит этот http-запрос?

Очень удобно использовать утилиту **nc** для отладки текстовых протоколов. Запустите её с флагом `-l` с указанием порта, который она будет прослушивать, и выполните свой POST-запрос на `localhost` в соседнем терминале.

```
nc -l 8080
curl http://localhost:8080/index.php -d name=myname -d age=26
```

Вы увидите примерно следующее

> ```
> POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 18
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> name=myname&age=26
> ```